# Checking SHA1 on a String

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

The word `Fox` produces the following sha1 hash:

`dfcd3454bbea788a751a696c24d97009ca992d17`

In python I'm simply trying to get this same output by doing the following:

```
import hashlib

myhash = hashlib.sha1("Fox".encode('utf-8'))
```

`myhash` just produces the following byte object:

`b'\xdf\xcd4T\xbb\xeax\x8au\x1ail$\xd9p\t\xca\x99-\x17'`

I've tried `binascii` and none of the methods there seem to be able to produce the above output.

How can I produce the resulting ascii hash from here?

Comment: `myhash.hexdigest()`

Comment: @vaultah thanks, but not looking for the hex digest

Comment: What do you mean by "ascii hash" then? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @free_mind: of course you are. `dfcd3454bbea788a751a696c24d97009ca992d17` is the hexadecimal representation of the digest, or *hex digest* in short.

Comment: OK you guys are right - sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a *hexadecimal representation* of a digest. You can use the [`hash.hexdigest()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) to produce the same in Python:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> myhash = hashlib.sha1("Fox".encode('utf-8'))
>>> myhash.digest()
b'\xdf\xcd4T\xbb\xeax\x8au\x1ail$\xd9p\t\xca\x99-\x17'
>>> myhash.hexdigest()
'dfcd3454bbea788a751a696c24d97009ca992d17'
```

You could also convert the binary digest to hexadecimal with the [`binascii.hexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(myhash.digest())
b'dfcd3454bbea788a751a696c24d97009ca992d17'
>>> binascii.hexlify(myhash.digest()).decode('ascii')
'dfcd3454bbea788a751a696c24d97009ca992d17'
```

However, that's just a more verbose way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, can't believe I missed something this simple!